# Optimize if condition jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this condition written in code.

I am not sure if it can be shorten or optimized.
Also would like to know that this can be considered as ideal way to write an
`if condition` & check few things at once.

```
if(isMobile() && (jQuery("body").hasClass("catalog-category-view") || jQuery("body").hasClass("catalog-product-view") || jQuery("body").hasClass("wishlist-index-index")) && !jQuery('.prev_btn').length && !jQuery('.next_btn').length){

console.log('condition');

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of tweaks you can make to shorten this:

- Alias `$` in the document.ready handler so you don't need to use `jQuery` everywhere.
- Use `is()` instead of `hasClass()`, as the former accepts multiple classes
- Combine `.prev_btn` and `.next_btn` in to a single jQuery object to check for `length`

```js
jQuery($ => {
  if (isMobile() && $('body').is('.catalog-category-view, .catalog-product-view, .wishlist-index-index') && !$('.prev_btn, .next_btn').length) {
    // do something...
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if will check like "||" "OR" ? with is function ?

Comment: Yes. `is()` will match on any of the selectors provided, so it's OR logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize the with following approach, though you can short by assigning some if conditions in a variable.

```
  var $body = jQuery("body");// get body jquery element in variable 
    //put OR conditions at the end as other condition can fail fast in the initial evaluation of if block
    if(isMobile() && !jQuery('.prev_btn').length && !jQuery('.next_btn').length && 
           ($body.hasClass("catalog-category-view") 
           || $body.hasClass("catalog-product-view") 
           || $body.hasClass("wishlist-index-index"))){
    
    console.log('condition');
    
    }
```

OR

```
    //put AND condition as first if block
    if(isMobile() && !jQuery('.prev_btn').length && !jQuery('.next_btn').length) {
     //put OR condition in second if block
     var $body = jQuery("body");// get body jquery element in variable  
     if( $body.hasClass("catalog-category-view") 
         || $body.hasClass("catalog-product-view") 
         || $body.hasClass("wishlist-index-index")){
    
    console.log('condition');
    }
    }
```